# Forms/Angular 4 - Display elements of an array of components in a dynamic number of columns

Tags: arrays, forms, angular

My objectif is to display the elements of a given array of components in a number of columns that changes dynamically.

**Example:**
Let's say that we have the following array:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]
```

If the number of columns is 3, the display of this array's elements would be:

```
a b c 
d e f
g h
```

Otherwise, if the number of columns is 5, the display would be:

```
a b c d e
f g h
```

**Implementation:**

I implemented a solution that serves my purpose in [this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zOSAVWoR7LgvvppissMu) (the number of columns is stored in the variable `columnsNumber`), but it's pure algorithmic and I am wondering if there would be better solutions.

**Usages:**

This solution can be used for example to construct dynamic forms, where each column contains a form's control or component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with the approach that you're using in the *plunker* is that the *function* "initArrayOfNumbers" is being called on every `ChangeDetection`.

To solve your problem I'd recommend you to use [**`SlicePipe`**](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe), like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let i of rows">
  <span *ngFor="let col of columns | slice: (i * columnSize): (i + 1) * columnSize">
    {{ col.name }}
  </span>
</div>
```

Where `rows` is defined here:

```
this.rows = Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(this.columns.length / this.columnSize) }, (v, k) => k);
```

**Explanation:**

It's a simple array containing a generated sequence, ie: if `columnSize` is 3 and your array is between (inclusive) 6 and 9 (inclusive) `rows` will be `[0, 1, 2]`, so you can use it to make calculations on `SlicePipe`.

You can check this simple [**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/KDijhcLF3OETPROorJgO) to see it working.

---

If you're looking for a more generic solution, you could create a custom `pipe`:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'chunk'
})
export class ChunkPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(input: any, size: number): any {

    if (!Array.isArray(input) || !size) {
      return [];
    }

    const intSize: number = parseInt(size, 10);
    return Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(input.length / intSize) }, (v, k) => input.slice(k * intSize, k * intSize + intSize));
  }
}
```

**Template**:

```
<div *ngFor="let col of columns | chunk: columnSize">
  <span *ngFor="let item of col">
    {{ item.name }}
  </span>
</div>
```

Also, don't forget to add the pipe to your declarations in `NgModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  declarations: [
    // Other declarations
    ChunkPipe
  ],
  ...
})
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/TDql2EuGdQY3S6Fcj8gH)

Comment: A nice and smart solution, the custom pipe is very handy